# Type deduce error for maxBound in a method with Constraints

Tags: haskell

I'm going thru `Get Programming with Haskell`, and try to extend some examples. Having a problem for a function to get the `maxBound` of Enum:

```
rotGen :: (Bounded a, Enum a) => a -> (a, Int)
rotGen x = (x, fromEnum (maxBound))
```

> Could not deduce (Bounded a0) arising from a use of ‘maxBound’
> from the context: (Bounded a, Enum a)

I understand the problem - `fromEnum (maxBound)` can't figure out which Bounded type to get the bound. But I don't know to to let the compiler know `it's the same type with x`.

I tried `fromEnum (maxBound :: a)` - doesn't work.

---

Solved.

FYI. This is a cleaner implementation of the ROT13 rotator for Lesson 15 of the `Get Programming with Haskell` book:

```
-- gen encoder & decoder for enum 
rotGen :: forall a . (Bounded a, Enum a) => (a -> a, a -> a)
rotGen = (\x -> toEnum ((half + fromEnum x) `mod` max), \x -> toEnum ((upper + fromEnum x) `mod` max))
 where
    max = 1 + fromEnum (maxBound @a)
    half = max `div` 2
    upper = max - half
```

(though as commented in the thread, language extension is too advanced for a newbie)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with the [**`ScopedTypeVariables`**](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/scoped_type_variables.html) and [**`TypeApplications`** extensions](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/type_applications.html). In that case we define `rotGen` as:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications #-}

rotGen :: forall a . (Bounded a, Enum a) => a -> (a, Int)
rotGen x = (x, fromEnum (maxBound @a))
```

With the `ScopedTypeVariables` we can make use of the type parameter `a` in the expression, and we should use an explicit `forall`. The `TypeApplication` extension will specify for what instance we use the `maxBound` constant.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use extensions for some reason, you can use `asTypeOf` instead:

```
rotGen x = (x, fromEnum (maxBound `asTypeOf` x))
```